# Proper options for mkisofs to create hybrid Mac and Windows ISO image?

Tags: mac, iso-image

I'd like to create ISO images that contain the full long filenames as well as retain any of the special Mac metadata used to denote folders as apps, etc. I cannot figure the proper options to give mkisofs. The best I can come up with is:

> mkisofs -hfs -Jr -o image directory

However, it lists a lot of warnings before it creates the images and I cannot help but think that I'm missing something. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

This is a dated post, but I'm encountering it currently so I'll add my fix for it:

```
    cd ~/path/to/OUTPUT_dir  
    mkisofs -o name.iso -hfs -J path_to_image
```

[mkisofs][-o filename.iso][options][image_location]

Makes a hfs/joliet compatible ISO file in your output_dir.  Remove the cd line to make the ISO file in your current dir.

Comment: Also: [mkisofs man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/mkisofs8.html)  Should be helpful.